# JBPM - Populate form on front-end with data structure from database

Tags: javascript, iframe, jbpm

Right now we're using a Javascript API to pull our JBPM user forms from the back-end and place them in an iframe which is sitting on our custom front-end.

What we'd like to do is pull data from one of our database servers and display it in a suggestion field on our front end (when someone starts typing an id, suggestions are displayed in the field). So the idea is that when someone selects an id this field will populate the underlying jbpm form with the appropriate data from the sql query.

Problem is:

- How to get at the jbpm form (field id's seem to be dynamic)

Anyone know of a potential solution to the specific or general problem?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Can you explain which ID field seems to be dynamic? from which jBPM class?

Comment: My initial thoughts were to bring the DB data to the front-end and hook it into work-bench form fields which are sitting in an iframe via their html id. But it appears that those id's have no type of consistency.

Instead we've decided to try to create a custom field directly in the work-bench which leverages our sql data.

Comment: Cool, it will be nice if you can show what you did in a blog post

Comment: My partner ran into some issues with that approach, but I'm not sure what the limitation was. Instead we moved on to the approach of persisting our own data and creating custom forms. Have also hit a limitation there, though, as our front end component has no reference to our environment, and, consequently, persistence strategies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue we ended up avoiding the jbpm forms altogether. Instead we used a Marionette/Backbone front end with our own forms and our own databases to store and display data. Our usage of JBPM 6.1 was scaled back to be used only for keeping track of where a particular process instance was in terms of human tasks.